# Bootstrap mobile app button size

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a user interface for a mobile application with HTML5/Bootstrap 3. I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Task Service</title>
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.1.0.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme-3.1.0.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="text-muted">Angular/Bootstrap Tasks</h3>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary form-control">
                Create
            </a>
        </div>
        <script src="lib/bootstrap-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The button is extremely small on my Windows Phone 8. It is about 1/4th the size of my finger.

How do I proceed making the appropriate size elements using bootstrap 3?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? The answers below are good, however, if you want to increase the button size **just** for mobile, then you'll need to add a class to the `.btn` and write some CSS in a media query to target the width(s) you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, this was a classical case of Microsoft incompetence.

Reference: http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/

> This is an issue because using CSS device adaptation is necessary for
>   getting responsive sites to work in snap mode in IE10 for Metro. So
>   while CSS device adaptation fixes our issues with snap mode, it causes
>   issues on Windows Phone 8 devices like the Lumia.
>
> My recommendation is to use Microsoft’s fix. Client-side UA sniffing
>   may not be the most eloquent solution, but I prefer it to potentially
>   harming the user experience—something which each of the other two
>   solutions would be guilty of. Perhaps this would be a different
>   scenario if this was IE8 or IE7, but considering it’s the behavior in
>   an operating system that just came out (and therefore, most likely
>   will only increase in marketshare for the time being) I think it’s
>   worth implementing.

Device width was not being applied, therefore screwing up the entire device display...

Answer (score 1):

also could be used this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your button.  It should read like: `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create<button>` rather than `<a class="btn btn-primary form-control">Create</a>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default button size by adding btn-lg, btn-sm or btn-xs so it's the size you'd like it to be.

So use:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control">
   Create
</a>
```

To use the larger size.

You could also override what's seen on each screen size by using the information [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). So you could use the regular size button like you are for a regular screen and have a different size for mobile devices. You'd have your content on the page twice, but wrap it with the appropriate responsive tags to get what you want.